# What is the purpose of the `keepIf` in Elm's zip code example?

Tags: elm

In the [zip code example](https://github.com/evancz/elm-lang.org/blob/5aa6e364df8eb234c4e3ad48904d769f1b516f94/public/examples/Reactive/ZipCodes.elm), there is the line:

```
responses = sendGet (fromMaybe "" <~ keepIf isJust Nothing realInput)
```

where `realInput :: Maybe String`. It seems to me that this can be reduced to:

```
responses = sendGet (fromMaybe "" <~ realInput)
```

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the two versions are exactly the same. The second parameter of `keepIf` is the "default value" to signal if the given condition does not hold. So the signal will be itself if it is Just, and Nothing if it is Nothing. :) I already filed a pull request: https://github.com/evancz/elm-lang.org/pull/18